# TensorFlow, Variable weights/layer1 already exists, disallowed

Tags: tensorflow

I was using TensorFlow and encountered an error related to the problem of variable reuse. My code is as follows:

```
INPUT_NODE = 3000
OUTPUT_NODE = 20
LAYER1_NODE = 500

def get_weight_variable(shape, regularizer):
    weights = tf.get_variable(
            "weights", shape,
            initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))

    if regularizer != None:
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', regularizer(weights))
    return weights


def inference(input_tensor, regularizer):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
        weights = get_weight_variable(
                [INPUT_NODE, LAYER1_NODE], regularizer)
        biases = tf.get_variable(
                "biases",[LAYER1_NODE],
                initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_tensor,weights) + biases)

    with tf.variable_scope('layer2'):
        weights = get_weight_variable(
                [LAYER1_NODE, OUTPUT_NODE], regularizer)
        biases = tf.get_variable(
                "biases",[OUTPUT_NODE],
                initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        layer2 = tf.matmul(layer1,weights) + biases

    return layer2

def train():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_NODE], name='x-input')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_NODE], name='y-input')

    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZATION_RATE)

    y = inference(x, regularizer)

    #with other codes follows#

def main(argv=None):
    train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

When I tried to run the code, an error occur:

```
ValueError: Variable layer1/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

I checked other answers on Stack Overflow. It seems that the problem is related to the use of

```
with tf.variable_scope():
```

or probably the version of TensorFlow? Anyone can help me deal with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to call `inference` in part `#with other codes follows#` you need to additional parameter `reuse`, something like this:

```
....

def inference(input_tensor, regularizer, reuse):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1', reuse = reuse):
     ....

def train():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_NODE], name='x-input')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_NODE], name='y-input')

    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZATION_RATE)

    y = inference(x, regularizer, False)

    #with other codes follows#

    z = inference(x, None, True)

    ....
```

First time you create variable in scope and next times you "reuse" it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! But actually I did not call inference function in the later part. This code was modified slightly from a tutorial on https://github.com/caicloud/tensorflow-tutorial/blob/master/Deep_Learning_with_TensorFlow/1.0.0/Chapter05/5.%20MNIST%E6%9C%80%E4%BD%B3%E5%AE%9E%E8%B7%B5/mnist_train.py, where you can see the source code.

Comment: If you show code in which error is appear we can talk more concrete.

This error can appear, if you try to get variable twice in same scope with same name without set reuse = True.

Comment: You are correct sir. The error occurs since this function is repeatedly called in the training process, although not explicitly called. You can click the link to show codes that follows which would the same as mine. Thanks again for pointing out the problem. I should figure out how to set the parameter reuse to True after it is called first time.